# JSON PUT Spring Roo

Tags: spring-roo

I have build a simple webapp with ROO, and added in JSON support.
POST, GET and DELETE work fine, however any PUT requests I make are acknowledged with a 200 OK message, and then nothing happens - see below:

```
**curl -i -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -d '{regexDef:"test99"}' http://myserver:8080/emdr/valuedomains/55

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 82
Date: Mon, 19 Nov 2012 17:35:44 GMT
{"datatype":"test22","id":55,"regexDef":null,"unitOfMeasure":"test99","version":0}MacBook-Pro:bin$**
```

The intention is to update the regexDef field, however although I'm getting an http 200 OK message from the server, the application is not updating the object as required, as is shown in the return - regexDef is still null.

Being new to ROO, and since all the JSON code is auto-generated I'm not sure exactly where to look in the generated files, so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the updateFromJson method in the controller.  You can reach this method by clicking right button on the red arrows (aspect markers) then Aspect Declarations -> ... .  I think you need to use STS to see these.

In this method, I see this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, headers = "Accept=application/json")
public ResponseEntity<String> AthleteController.updateFromJson(@RequestBody String json) {
```

You can see here there is no mention an "id" in the request mapping.  This means you are using the wrong path to invoke this method.  Also, you need pass the id as part of the json payload, so it knows which object to update.